# Looping RF classification in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

Is it possible to run a classification repeatedly and generate the mode of all classified outputs in Google Earth Engine?

I have successfully performed a single-run of the Random Forest classification with a set of training data but have two more independently collected training data points to use.

Is it possible to have a loop introduced in GEE for this task?

The aim of the classification is to delineate waterbodies from surrounding vegetated land cover classes.

Please see link for the codes:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/lexisgis/WaterMapping

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Does `classified1.addBands(classified2).addBands(...).mode()` do it?  It's not clear what you mean by looping over classifiers, but you could do something like this:

```
var numTrees = ee.List.sequence(5, 50, 5);

var forests = numTrees.map(function(t) {
  return ee.Classifier.randomForest(t)
      .train({
        features: training, 
        classProperty: 'class', 
        inputProperties: image.bandNames()
      });
});
```

Of course, you might want to substitute different training sets, or even different classifiers for `t`.  Whatever you use, train the classifier, classify the thing, and take the mode of the ensemble.

EDIT:
In answer to your answer (and comment), here it is returning classified images:

```
// Here, image is a previously defined image to classify.
// It has bands match the properties in training.
var images = numTrees.map(function(t) {
      var classifier ee.Classifier.randomForest(t)
          .train({
            features: training, 
            classProperty: 'class', 
            inputProperties: image.bandNames()
          });
      return image.classify(classifier);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, generated 3 trained RF classifiers with 3 different training data (see codes below). Cannot seem to figure out how to generate 3 classified images. Could you assist with this please? Still trying to get around GEE. Thanks again.
    var features = ee.List([train1, train2, train3]);
    var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'nd'];
    var classifier = features.map(function(t) {
      return ee.Classifier.randomForest({numberOfTrees: 500})
          .train({
            features: t, 
            classProperty: 'class', 
            inputProperties: bands
          })
    });

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly.  Please upvote if this helps you.  Also, no need to follow up with another answer that asks a follow-up question.